# Zookeeper can work with Pacemaker?

Tags: apache-zookeeper, high-availability, pacemaker

As mentioned in the title, do you think Zookeeper can work with Pacemaker instead of Corosync? Is there any examination about that?

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Please move your question to http://serverfault.com

Comment: thanks for your reminding